# Parallel each loop on Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, parallel-processing, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following code:

```
    var1 = 0
    var2 = 0

    group_ids.each do |id|
        result = PerformanceService.new(
            group_id: id,
            date_start: prev_month,
            date_end: prev_month.end_of_month
        ).call

        totals = ResultTotals.new(result, 0)

        var1 += totals.var1
        var2 += totals.var2
    end
```

The 'call' method makes database querys, calculations and other stuff to get the performance result (which is an array) of a group.

Then that result is used to get the 'totals' of the group and finally to get 'var1' and 'var2' values. These variable values have to be added to those of the other groups to obtain the final results.

The problem is that when the number of groups to be processed is very large, this calculation takes a long time. The performance of 'call' method can't be optimized much further, so I'd like to find the way to speed up this and I think that parallelize the loop is a good way to achieve it.

I tried the gem 'parallel', using 'in_processes' and 'in_threads', but the calculation time did not improve.

How can I improve the calculation time of this loop? The way to improve it does not have to be parallelizing. I can use any alternative you propose.

If it helps, I'm using Ruby 2.5, Rails 5.2 and PostgreSQL 11.7 as database.

Comment: _"The 'call' method makes database querys"_ – that could be the bottleneck. How do those queries look like? Have to tried to make them a single query?

Comment: Do you have appropriate indexes on your database tables?

Comment: @Stefan, maybe the querys can be reduced, but, if not, how would you reduce the execution time? By paralleling?

Comment: @spickermann, yes, there are indexes on the fields I use.

Comment: You first have to _measure_ and once you found out what’s slow, you can try optimizing that part. Or find a different approach.